# Cannot pull Data Layer Variable in Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel, google-datalayer

I want to implement [Facebook Advanced Matching Manually](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/advanced/advanced-matching/) using Google Tag Manager. I did the following:

**On GTM, I did the following:**

1. Created a variable named `AdvancedMatchingVariable` of the type Data
   Layer Variable with Variable Name `advancedMatching`
2. I Updated Facebook Base Code Tag to include the new variable as follows:

```js
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
...
fbq('init', 'pixel id',
  '{{AdvancedMatchingVariable}}'
);
</script>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

**On my Website, I added this code:**

```
dataLayer.push({
  'advancedMatching': {
      'em': '$email',
      'fn': '$fname',
      'ln': '$lname'
     }
});
```

However, It didn't work. I get Object Object in the facebook pixel base code. As the following:

```js
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
fbq('init', '*ID*', 
    Object Object
  );
</script>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

So please what is the problem with my code? I have been searching and trying to fix it for hours!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to parse the values of the `advancedMatching` object yourself in the FB pixel, like

```
fbq('init', 'pixel id', {
    em: advancedMatching.em,
    fn: advancedMatching.fn,
    ln: advancedMatching.ln
});
```

You could probably write a helper function to map this for you, if you have dynamic tracking parameters in `advancedMatching`.

Comment: Thank you, Beck. I have dynamic parameters in `advancedMatching`. Can you help me to write the helper function? I am more to marketing than development.

Comment: function GetFBParameters() {
        return dataLayer.find(function(i) {
            if (i.hasOwnProperty("advancedMatching")) {
                return i;
            }
        })["advancedMatching"];
    }

fbq('init', 'pixel id', GetFBParameters());

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Thank you anyway, Beck.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify your pixel code to remove the quotes around like so:

```js
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
...
fbq('init', 'pixel id',
  {{AdvancedMatchingVariable}}
);
</script>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Comment: I already tried it, but not working. I get this:

`fbq('init", 'pixel id', google_tag_manager [GTM-XXXX].macro...`